# ng2-highcharts chart update after load

Tags: highcharts, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I'm using angular 2, firebase and ng2-highcharts.

I assign data after I receive them from firebase like so :

```
this.items = af.database.list('/items');
this.optionsAsync = this.items.map(data => {
    this.options.series[0].data = data.map(item => ([item.x, item.y]));
    return this.options;
});
```

Then in my view template I have :

```
<div [ng2-highcharts]="optionsAsync | async"></div>
```

This is working fine at first load. But unfortunately when new data are received chart is not updated. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by referencing highcharts component with `@ViewChild` like so :

in component class :

```js
import { ViewChild, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [Ng2Highcharts]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(Ng2Highcharts)
  chartElement: Ng2Highcharts;

  private chartData = {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        colors: ['rgba(255,0,255,1)'],
        title: {
            text: 'Items'
        },
        credits: '',
        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'Items',
            data: []
        }]
  };
  chartData$ = new Subject();

  ngOnInit() {
      this.items.subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.chartData.series[0].data = data.map(item => ([item.x, parseFloat(item.y)]) );
        this.chartData$.next(this.chartData);
        if(this.chartElement && this.chartElement.chart) {
          var serieRef = this.chartElement.chart.series[0];
          serieRef.setData(this.chartData.series[0].data);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Did it worked using multiple series with different colors?